# How to return the getText() values in array using protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to return the options present in the list using the below function.

**HTML**

```
<select>
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option>three</option>
<select>
```

**Function**

```
getValues(){
  var ele = element(by.xpath("......../select"));
  return ele.all(by.tagName('option')).getAttribute('value').getText().then(function (text){
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    text[i] = text[i].trim();
  }
  return text;
 });
```

}

When I print the values in console using `console.log(getValues())`, the console displays the`ManagedPromise{.....}` function instead of options.

But I'm expecting the options as `["one","two","three"]` array. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you add the HTML where you are trying to do this?

Comment: getValues().then(function(values){ console.log(values)})

Comment: @SureshSalloju My issue is I need to return the values as array. I can able to print the values.

Comment: your select isn't closed correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why create a complex method for it if you can also do it like this

```js
getValues() {
  return element.all(by.css('select option')).getText();
}
```

The `getText()` can also be executed on a ElementFinderArray and it will return a promise that contains `['one', 'two', 'three']`

**Update: with trim function**

First of all your code will not work because of 2 reasons:

1. protractor uses promises, you first needs to resolve the promises before you can use the value. See also 1 of your previous questions you asked
2. You are using `.getAttribute('value').getText()`. This will never work.

Below you will find a working example in 3 different styles.

```js
// with your code
getValues() {
  var ele = element(by.xpath("......../select"));
  return ele.all(by.tagName('option'))
    .map(function(option) {
      return option.getText()
        .then(function(optionText) {
          return optionText.trim();
        });
    });
}

// with protractor shorthand notation
getValues() {
  return $$('select option').map((option) => {
    return option.getText()
      .then((optionText) => {
        return optionText.trim();
      });
  });
}

// 1 line
getValues() {
  return $$('select option').map((option) => option.getText().then((optionText) => optionText.trim()));
}
```

Comment: Before returning the value I need to trim the values. So only create the above function.

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way is to use `.map()`.
See the [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.map).

The only thing you need to remember is that `.map()` returns `A promise that resolves to an array of values returned by the map function.`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<select id="sel">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<p>Click the button to display values</p>

<button onclick="clickHandler()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>  
</body>
<script "text/javacript">
function clickHandler() {
    var options = document.getElementById("sel").childNodes;
    let results =[];
    [].forEach.call(options, function(option) {
      if (option instanceof HTMLOptionElement) {
        results.push(option.text); 
        // Swap for option.value if you like too would be lower case
      }
    });
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = results.toString();
}
</script>
</html>
```

See live demo [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FH0P5XL2HYKQ)
 
[HTMLOptionElement on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement)